# Basic program to convert Roman number Arabic form?

Tags: c++, clion

I am wanting some help in answering these two questions. The first one is this:

1. I am trying to write a program that converts a single Roman number in the range I (1) to IX (9) to Arabic form. The
   program should read a single string from standard input and print the corresponding value to standard output.

I then want to Extend the program so that it works correctly when the input consists of either lower case or upper case Roman letters.
The simplest approach is to convert each character in the input word into uppercase before trying to find a match. Run a
loop over the characters in the string using the index operator ([]) to access each character and use the toupper
function (you will need to include the cctype header file) to get the corresponding uppercase value.

For the second question this is what it wants me to do next:

2. Extend the program so that it can deal with single digit numbers of any value. A single digit number is one that consists
   only of thousands, hundreds, tens, or units. Thus LXX (70) and CD (400) are single digit numbers, but XIV (14) and
   MC (1100) are not. Use the same approach as for units digits, but with 4 different arrays, one each for the thousands,
   hundreds, tens, and units digits. Try looking for thousands digits first, then for hundreds, and so on. When you find a
   match in one of the arrays, print the corresponding value and stop.
   Modify the program so that it reads and converts all input numbers until end of file (eof) on standard input. You will
   probably be able to do this by simply adding an appropriate reading loop around the code that reads a single line.

Currently this is what i have to start but am unsure how to write a program like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <stdexcept>
using namespace std;


class RomanNumeral
{
public:
    const static int M = 1000;
    const static int D = 500;
    const static int C = 100;
    const static int L = 50;
    const static int X = 10;
    const static int V = 5;
    const static int I = 1;

    RomanNumeral( const int arabic ) :
            m_roman( "" ),
            m_arabic( ((arabic > 0) ? arabic : 0) )
    {
        if( arabic > 0 )
        {
            int i = arabic;
            while( i > 0 )
            {
                if( ( i - M ) >= 0 )
                {
                    m_roman += "M";
                    i -= M;
                    continue;
                }
                if( ( i - D ) >= 0 )
                {
                    m_roman += "D";
                    i -= D;
                    continue;
                }
                if( ( i - C ) >= 0 )
                {
                    m_roman += "C";
                    i -= C;
                    continue;
                }
                if( ( i - L ) >= 0 )
                {
                    m_roman += "L";
                    i -= L;
                    continue;
                }
                if( ( i - X ) >= 0 )
                {
                    m_roman += "X";
                    i -= X;
                    continue;
                }
                if( ( i - V ) >= 0 )
                {
                    m_roman += "V";
                    i -= V;
                    continue;
                }
                if( ( i - I ) >= 0 )
                {
                    m_roman += "I";
                    i -= I;
                    continue;
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            m_roman = "0";
        }
    }

    RomanNumeral( const std::string& string ) :
            m_roman( ((string.size() > 0 ) ? string : "0" ) ),
            m_arabic( 0 )
    {
        int i = 0;
        while( i < (int)string.size() )
        {
            char c = string[i++];
            switch( c )
            {
                case 'M':
                case 'm':
                    m_arabic += M;
                    break;
                case 'D':
                case 'd':
                    m_arabic += D;
                    break;
                case 'C':
                case 'c':
                    m_arabic += C;
                    break;
                case 'L':
                case 'l':
                    m_arabic += L;
                    break;
                case 'X':
                case 'x':
                    m_arabic += X;
                    break;
                case 'V':
                case 'v':
                    m_arabic += V;
                    break;
                case 'I':
                case 'i':
                    m_arabic += I;
                    break;
                default:
                    throw new std::out_of_range( "Not a valid Roman numeral!" );
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    int getArabic()
    {
        return m_arabic;
    }
    void setArabic( const int arabic );
    const std::string& getRoman()
    {
        return m_roman;
    }
protected:
    std::string m_roman;
    int m_arabic;
};

int main()
{


    std::string roman;
    cin >> roman;
    try
    {
        RomanNumeral rn( roman );

        cout <<  rn.getArabic() << endl;
    }
    catch( exception* ex )
    {
        cout << roman << " " << ex->what() << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Have been doing some tutorials on it but came across this question on a website the other day but I can't find the solution to this to see how its done. Could you demonstrate how to write a program like this by any chance?

Comment: Please one question per question and for questions about code you should include a [mcve] in the question

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question Please try something and ask about a specific problem. "How to write code?" is not a useful question

Comment: Do you know how to convert Roman number to Arabic on paper? Write down a couple examples and solve them on paper. Once you are sure you understand every quirk, go code!

Comment: [Converting roman numerals to decimals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17724887/c-converting-roman-numerals-to-decimals) has some good answers for this problem

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you're stuck on a problem, try to decompose it into steps and implementing the things you can.

Step one is reading a single word:

```
std::string word;
std::cin >> word;
```

Step two is converting the word into a number:

```
int convert_to_number(const std::string& w) {
  if (w == "I") return 1;
  if (w == "II") return 2;
  // and so on.
}
```

Step three is doing the conversion and printing the result:

```
std::cout << convert_to_number(word) << std::endl;
```

Instead of writing large amounts of `if` statements, you may want to try using an `std::map<std::string, int>` or `std::unordered_hash<std::string, int>` for a constant-time lookup.

Comment: Okay, I manged to figure a way out but for some reason  when i input 9 in roman numerals as IX it gives me as arabic output 11. When  i input 4 in roman numerals it gives me 6 in arabic numbers. Why is this so, what is the fix to this???

Comment: Your loop in `RomanNumeral( const std::string& string )` does not take into account the "subtractive" rule (ie "IV" = 5 - 1). Step through the code with a debugger and verify for yourself. The fix is to remember the last letter and see if it is smaller than the current letter. Finally, I believe the subtractive rule only applies to "I", unless you think "VM" is an acceptable way of writing 995 ;)